# Problem in understanding some aspects of "The Pizza Ontology "

Tags: ontology, protege

I am now reading the guide to building ontology using Protege tutorial that deals with the famous Pizza example. There are two thing that I don't understand in particular.

Shouldn't American/AmericanHot/Margherita/Soho(and all sublclasses mentioned inside the NamedPizza class in the ontology) rather be individuals of the class Pizza? I mean it is natural to think that they are individuals of a class Pizza. Why have they considered these to be subclasses rather than individuals. And how do they plan to make individuals out of it?(like Margherita1, Margherita2, and so on .... If so, why don't they create any such individuals in the individuals tab)?

And why is that they apply closure axiom only to subclasses of NamedPizza and not others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ontology can be modeled in different ways and I think the way you are suggesting should result in a correct ontology. 
You can use the same rules to define a subclass as in OOP. If the class has a unique property or relation define a new class else instance should be alright.